# is it normal to get an exception?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I'm using asp.net and when I press the play button to start debugging, all works fine. The page I'm debugging makes ajax calls to a web service. Then, I press stop. When I trigger another call from the page in the browser, I get an error back.

Am I getting this error because something broke in the back-end (but since I stopped debugging I can't see what it it) or is it that when you press the stop button, the entire application stops? The reason I'm asking is that when I press the preview button on the same page, the ajax calls work fine even thought the app in not being debugged.

Thanks,

Comment: when you say "stop the debugging" does the Cassini server stop serving pages? If so, then yes, that's normal. If Cassini is still running, then no, that's not normal. Can you run it in IIS Express?

Comment: Well I'm not sure; does pressing the STOP button in VS stop Cassini altogether or just the current debugging?

Comment: It usually just detaches the debugger, but Cassini is still working, to make sure: a small icon is served on the tray whenever Cassini is running, for each instance of Cassini.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to look at the process explorer to see which process is starting/ending when you press "start/stop debug". 
If the back end is yours and you've got source codes, than start another Visual Studio instance and run the backend in the debug mode to see what's happening there...